# How to Change ActionBar title in fragment class in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-actionbar

I'm new to android development in kotlin. I tried the following code to change the actionbar title from my fragment.It's not working.Please help

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


    activity.actionBar?.title = "Example 1"
    countBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    toastBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
    randomBtn.setOnClickListener(this)

}
```

`MainActivity.kt` code is as below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    val actionBar = supportActionBar
    actionBar?.title = getString(R.string.toolbar_title)
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It seems like you're setting the support action bar, so you'd have to use the support action bar in the `onCreateView` method too. The `actionBar` is null, that's why the code to set the title won't run.

Try this out:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

  (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Example 1"
  //...
}
```

The other problem I think you might run into is that you're adding the support action bar in the activity's `onCreate` method, but you're trying to access it in the fragment's `onViewCreated` which comes before according to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png) (I haven't really tried this out, it's just from looking at the diagram). If this is the case, then you'd have to change it. Maybe try the `onStart` from the fragment.

Comment: Activity doesn't have getSuppotActionBar function, so it needs to be cast to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I moved the code to onStart method and also changed actionBar to supportActionBar. but then supportActionBar becomes a unresolved reference

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention that you need to cast the activity to the support activity too (which I guess you can do since you used the support action bar). I've updated the answer. I assume you extend `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: using this.supportActionBar?.title = "Example 1" in kotlin lang.

Answer (score 2):

this page explain very well how to set a Toolbar :

https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up#kotlin

than changing things on the tool bar:

```
setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
supportActionBar!!.title = "new title of toolbar"
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me on the onViewCreated Method

```
override fun onViewCreated() {    
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(toolbar_name)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = getString(R.string.title)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu)

    (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "My Fragment Title"

}
```

Comment: Use setSupportActionBar(true) on top of the title statement.